# How to manipulate matrices whose elements are themselves matrices or other unique entities?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Matrices are excellent for manipulating frames of reference. Those whose members are not restricted a common set of numbers/entities (or are themselves matrices) are extremely useful to me.

Their use in the manipulation of concepts is essential in building knowledge representations.

Are there others who are manipulating matrices whose elements are themselves matrices or other unique entities? If so, how are they doing it?

Comment: Your 'clarification' made it all blur..

Comment: Why? In what way?

Comment: What is this $A^B$ here?

Comment: It is one of many forms of the manipulation I am referring to. It refers to a shift in holarchy (hierarchy type). I've been thinking of removing it ever since your comment, but I cannot. I will do so only if I cannot get an answer without its removal. If you could just ignore the 'clarification' and answer it as if it were posed in a fashion more acceptable to you, I would appreciate it so very much. I almost get an ulcer at posing questions like this anyway, because I know how vicious some of the answers may be.

Comment: Reluctantly deleted...in the hope that this important question doesn't get completely ignored.

Comment: Exactly what 'manipulations' are you talking about? We can define matrices with usual operations with entries in any given *ring* $R$, so in particular we can take $R$ to be a ring of square matrices..

Comment: I am aware of this definition. Let us remain with them at this point. Your answer to the question in that context would be appreciated.
Regarding your question about manipulations, I'm interested in all/some/any of the operators, structure, properties,... of matrices that relate to my question.

Comment: That's all. I know not too much about these. Do you want to multiply your matrices? Or what manipulations?

Comment: Should we move this discussion to a chat? I'm getting 'stress behaviour' from Stack Exchange now, because of the length of this discussion.
As to your question: yes, for a first run let's do their multiplication. I learnt linear algebra long ago so I'm sure I'll understand what you write. I'm interested in any and all knowledge about this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming to maintain the usual matrix operations, i.e. to obtain a *ring*, we can formulate a minimum requirement on the structures  of the sets where the entries are coming from.

Even in the most common case when all entries are from the same ring $R$, we can allow $R$ itself to be a matrix ring, moreover we can iterate it as well..

But we can consider different sets $A_{ij}$ (with at least Abelian group structure for the addition) holding the possible $i, j$-entries. 
Note that the diagonal sets $A_{ii} $ must be themselves rings, but we can relax it somehow for the other entries.

For instance, the generalized matrix rings of the form $\pmatrix{R&M\\ \{0\} &S} $ are exactly those where $R$ and $S$ are rings and $M$ is an $R$-$S$-bimodule.

The $2\times2$ generalized matrix rings $\pmatrix{R&M\\N&S}  $ correspond to *Morita contexts* between rings $R$ and $S$, connecting the bimodules ${}_RM_S$ and ${}_SN_R$.

That's all my knowledge on the topic.